# No error but not able to get desired results in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to find the percentage price jump (+-15 % change) in the numbers and when there is the jump it will give me the corresponding date. However, when there is a first jump it will break-out from the inner-for loop gives me the correspndong data for it and which will get store in temp.cyc data frame.

The program is not showing any error but it is repeating the same no. throughout and when I check the value of test.df it is showing NA.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on? And I am new to R so it will helpful if you can give your answer in detail. Thank You :)

```
 # Defining variables
  row= nrow(price.close)
  col=ncol(price.close)

#Defining Matrix 
  m<-matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=row)
  p<-matrix(0,ncol=5,nrow=row)

# Dataframe to temporaily store percentage Change
  test.df<- vector(mode="numeric", length=nrow(price.close))

# Dataframe to extract required Values
  temp.cyc<-as.data.frame(p)
  colnames(temp.cyc)<-c("cyc.duration","Start.date","End.date","Start.date.value","End.date.value")




for( j in 1:row)
  {
    for(i in j:row)
    {
       test.df<-(price.close[(i+1),2]-price.close[j,2])/price.close[j,2]



     if(test.df >= 0.15 | test.df <= -0.15 | is.na(test.df)== TRUE )
          { 

            temp.cyc$Start.date.value = price.close[j,2]
            temp.cyc$End.date.value  <- price.close[i,2]
            temp.cyc$Start.date      <- price.close[j,1]
            temp.cyc$End.date        <- price.close[i,1]
           }  

           break

    }
  }
```

Comment: You're adding to the first row of the temp.cyc every time. If you want to grow the temp.cyc data.frame each time, then you'll have to `rbind()` the new values to it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are using this for financial data , e.g. stock prices.  If this assumption is right then I suggest that you should use packages that have this functionality.  I would suggest **quantmod** [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/index.html).

Here's short example how to get dates when price goes more then 15% up or down.

```
library(quantmod)


# create some dummy stock data over 10 days period
# next time I hope you will attach some of your data
stockClose <- c(100,50,75,70,68,100,115,120,130,100)
stockDates <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),length=10,by="+1 days")
stock.xts <- as.xts(stockClose,stockDates)

# calculate change , check '?Delt' help for more info 
change <- Delt(stock.xts)

#get only those rows where price change in both directions is higher then 15%
specialDays <- change[coredata(change) < -0.15 | coredata(change) > 0.15,]

#get dates
justDates <- index(specialDays)
```

which gives us "2014-01-02" ,"2014-01-03" ,"2014-01-06" and  "2014-01-10"

In case you want to actually compare all possible combinations for entering and exiting position then you can use something like this :

```
library(quantmod)

calculatePeriods <- function(){


  stockClose <- c(100,50,75,70,68,100,115,120,130,100)

  stockDates <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),length=10,by="+1 days")


  stock.xts <- as.xts(stockClose,stockDates)

  # you will be adding rows to thid df
  result <- data.frame()


  for(i in 1:(length(stock.xts)-1)){


    for(j in 2:length(stock.xts)){

      change <- (coredata(stock.xts[j])-coredata(stock.xts[i]))/coredata(stock.xts[i])

      if(change < (-0.15) | change > (0.15)){

        row <- data.frame("cyc.duration"=as.numeric(index(stock.xts[j])-index(stock.xts[i]),units="days"),"Start.date"=index(stock.xts[i]),"End.date"=index(stock.xts[j]),"Start.date.value"=coredata(stock.xts[i]),"End.date.value"=coredata(stock.xts[j]))
        result <- rbind(result,row)
      }

    }


  }
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for let me know about quantmod package but still it doesn't solve my purpose. Here it is taking stock Close consecutively. But what I want is that it should give me the time period from the beginning when price got up/down by 15%. For eg. your first stock close is 100 than instead of  it should give me the first instance when its is up/down by 15% In this case it will be the next period but suppose 50 was the last element then it should give me 10 days jump. Hope I am able to make you understand my problem.

Comment: sure. but how can I attach my file ??

Comment: attach it somewhere on the net and then share a link here.  Check here for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: For that matter you can use any data. like the link :  https://www.quandl.com/CBOE/GVK2011-Gold-Volatility-Index-Futures-May-2011-GVK2011